# The Boto3 EC2 client describe_images method documentation says it returns PlatformDetails and UsageOperation for an image, but it doesn't

Tags: boto3

I really want to know the values of the 2 fields PlatformDetails and UsageOperation for an image, and the Boto3 EC2 documentation for describe_images says that those fields are included in the results of that method, but when I try it, I get an error message 
`AttributeError: 'ec2.Image' object has no attribute 'platform_details'`

Using the AWS EC2 command line, I can get this information, so I don't think there's any problem with my credentials:
`aws ec2 describe-images --region us-east-2 --image-ids ami-07295239562398` (not the actual ID)

Using both describe_images and the more direct 
`image = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name = 'us-east-2').Image('ami-07295239562398')` and checking for image.platform_details and image.usage_operation give errors.
All the other fields I expect are included - state, platform, image_id, description etc.

Are these fields supposed to be part of the ec2.Image? Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: 1. Check if boto3 version is the same as the docs you're referring to. 2. Maybe not every image has that parameter, check by using same AMI ID and using client method `EC2.Client.describe_images` instead of `EC2.Image.platform_details`.

Comment: 2. Using the CLI for the same image I do get the PlatformDetails, and have used both describe_images and Image.platform_details.

1. Having upgraded to boto3 1.13.2, which is the version the documentation refers to, I still have the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrading to boto3 1.13.2 works for me.

Comment: I upgraded to boto3 1.13.2, and have the same problem.

Comment: Can you do a `pip install botocore --upgrade` too?

Comment: That's exactly what I did

And I've tried python 2.7 and 3.8

Comment: Oh, I thought you did `pip install boto3 --upgrade`. Please try this as well.

Comment: sorry, reading things without noticing what they actually say.

Comment: but, it appears to have upgraded botocore as part of boto3. 
'Requirement already satisfied'. So botocore is at 1.16.2

Comment: thanks for your help. something has started working. Maybe just needed a new cmd window open to run my python.

Comment: Or maybe I was being stupid. While trying lots of different variations of platform_details (or PlatformDetails) I left the wrong one in after upgrading boto3.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to boto3 1.13.2 if you want the documentation for boto3 1.13.2 to be accurate.